# read large file excel with multiple worksheet to json with python

Tags: json, excel, python-3.x, pandas, multithreading

I have a large excel file and have multiple worksheets its 100 MB

sheet A

```
id | name | address
1  | joe  |  A
2  | gis  |  B
3  | leo  |  C
```

work_1

```
id| call
1 | 10
1 | 8
2 | 1
3 | 3
```

work_2

```
id| call
2 | 4  
3 | 8
3 | 7
```

desired json for each id

```
data = { id: 1,
address: A,
name: Joe,
log : [{call:10}, {call:8 }]
}
data= { id: 2,
address: B,
name: Gis,
log : [{call:1}, {call:4}]
}
data= { id: 3,
address: C,
name: Leo,
log : [{call:3}, {call:8}, {call:7}]
}
```

i've tried with pandas but it takes 5 minutes to run it and it only read_excel without any processing. is there any solution to make it faster and how to get desired json?

maybe divide the process into chunk(but pandas removed chunksize for read_excel) and add some threading to make interval so the procees could be print each batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
works=pd.concat([work1,work2],ignore_index=True)
mapper_works=works.groupby('id')[['call']].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records'))
dfa['log']=dfa['id'].map(mapper_works)
data=dfa.reindex(columns=['id','address','name','log']).to_dict('records')
print(data)
```

---

**The output is a list of dict for each `id`:**

```
[{'id': 1, 'address': 'A', 'name': 'joe', 'log': [{'call': 10}, {'call': 8}]},
 {'id': 2, 'address': 'B', 'name': 'gis', 'log': [{'call': 1}, {'call': 4}]},
 {'id': 3, 'address': 'C', 'name': 'leo', 'log': [{'call': 3}, {'call': 8}, {'call': 7}]}
]
```

---

If you want you can assign to a column:

```
dfa['dicts']=data
print(dfa)

   id name address                                      log  \
0   1  joe       A              [{'call': 10}, {'call': 8}]   
1   2  gis       B               [{'call': 1}, {'call': 4}]   
2   3  leo       C  [{'call': 3}, {'call': 8}, {'call': 7}]   

                                               dicts  
0  {'id': 1, 'address': 'A', 'name': 'joe', 'log'...  
1  {'id': 2, 'address': 'B', 'name': 'gis', 'log'...  
2  {'id': 3, 'address': 'C', 'name': 'leo', 'log'...
```